# Define start date of second date picker from first date picker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am working on having two bootstrap date pickers, once the user clicks on any date on the first date-picker the start date of the second date picker should be that, selected in the first date picker and before that all dates should be disabled.

But certainly I am going some wrong way I could not figure out.The value of the variable diffDays is not being reflected in the startDate field of the second date-picker and therefore the start date is not being reflected in second date-picker.

Below is the code:

```
function checkDate(startDate) {
    var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var res = startDate.value.split("/");
    var firstDate = new Date(res[2], res[1] - 1, res[0]);
    var todayFullDate = new Date();
    var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - todayFullDate
            .getTime())
            / (oneDay)));

    $('#date2').datepicker({

        startDate: '+'+diffDays+'d'
                });

}
$(function() {

    $('#date1').datepicker({
        format : "dd/mm/yyyy",
        required : true,

    });

    $("#register-form").validate({

        rules : {
            date1 : "required"
        },

        messages : {
            date1 : "Please enter a valid date"
        },

        submitHandler : function(form) {

            form.submit();
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of simple `methods` and `options` provided along with their plugin as below:

**[`changeDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate)**, **[`setStartDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setstartdate)** and **[`setEndDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setenddate)** are the 3 important things you need to make use of.

**[`changeDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate)** is an `event` which is *`fired when the date is changed`*.

**[`setStartDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setstartdate)** and **[`setEndDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setenddate)** are the 2 methods which sets `startdate` and `enddate` for respective `datepickers`. You need to attach `changeDate` event to both the `datepickers` and set corresponding start and end dates for respective `datepickers` as below

```
$('.start').datepicker({
    autoclose:true
}).on('changeDate',function(e){
    //on change of date on start datepicker, set end datepicker's date
    $('.end').datepicker('setStartDate',e.date)
});

$('.end').datepicker({
    autoclose:true
}).on('changeDate',function(e){
    //on change of date on end datepicker, set start datepicker's date
    //e.date will have selected date value.
    $('.start').datepicker('setEndDate',e.date)
})
```

## `DEMO HERE`

Comment: Great Answer. million Thanks!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)